# Access "busy" array in google calendar api

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Trying to use the [freebusy](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy) query in Google Calendar API. I've followed the example provided at the [Googleapis documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/calendar/classes/Resource$Freebusy.html#query) and I do get the result, but the busy information is just shown as an `[Array]`, without the actual busy information.

The code (just the relevant part):

```
const res = await calendar.freebusy.query({
        requestBody: {
            timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
            timeMax: '2021-03-25T23:00:00+01:00',
            items: [
                {
                   id: 'calendarid'
                }
            ]
        },
    });

    console.log(res.data);
```

Gets a correct response (meaning there's no error), but the response always shows the "busy" property as [Array]:

```
{
  kind: 'calendar#freeBusy',
  timeMin: '2021-03-20T10:39:42.000Z',
  timeMax: '2021-03-25T22:00:00.000Z',
  calendars: {
    'calendarid': { busy: [Array] }
  }
}
```

The correct complete result (as tested using [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query)):

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
 "timeMin": "2021-03-20T11:00:00.000Z",
 "timeMax": "2021-03-25T22:00:00.000Z",
 "calendars": {
  "calendarid": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2021-03-22T18:00:00Z",
     "end": "2021-03-22T19:00:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2021-03-24T13:00:00Z",
     "end": "2021-03-24T16:00:00Z"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Any idea how to access the information in the "busy" array...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you console log a nested object(or response body in your case), you see nested object value as `[object object]` or `[Array]`. You can still parse the object to get your nested values but if you want to see the complete response in console log, you can try `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data))`.

To parse the response and get `busy` array.

```
const busyArray = res.data.calendars.calendarid.busy;
```

Comment: thanks, JSON.stringify was spot on what made it work. But additionally, the "calendarid" is in the format "somethingsomething@group.calendar.google.com". So I can't call "res.data.calendars.somethingsomething@group.calendar.google.com.busy". How do I get to { "start", "end" } objects of this array?

Comment: In this case you can access the property with index notation like `res.data.calendars[calendarIdVariable].busy`. But before using this, you will have to store calendar id in `calendarIdVariable` variable.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much - I know it was quite trivial, so appreciate the schooling. Marking this resolved.

Comment: Glad to be of help.